# How to change signal handler in child-process?

Tags: c, signals, child-process, job-control

I'm writing a shell with job control. The main process should ignore stop-signals and handle SIGCHLD. Child process after fork() should set signals to SIG_DFL. The problem is that my child process ignores signals too.

At the start of my program I set shell to foreground and initialize signals

```c
...
tcsetpgrp(shell_terminal, shell_pgid);
set_signals();

void    chld_handler(int signum)
{
    if (signum == SIGCHLD)
        check_and_wait();
    return ;
}

void    set_signals() {
    sigset_t set;
    struct sigaction act;

    sigfillset(&set);
    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &set, NULL);

    ft_memset(&act, 0, sizeof(act));

    sigfillset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;

    sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGQUIT, &act, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGTSTP, &act, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGTERM, &act, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGTTIN, &act, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGTTOU, &act, NULL);

    act.sa_handler = chld_handler;

    sigaction(SIGCHLD, &act, NULL);

    sigemptyset(&set);
    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &set, NULL);
    return;
}
```

after fork() in child process:

```c
/* set to foreground */
pid = getpid();
if (!job->pgid)
    job->pgid = pid;
setpgid(pid, job->pgid);
tcsetpgrp(shell_terminal, job->pgid);

/* set signals */
sigset_t set;
struct sigaction act;

sigfillset(&set);
sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &set, NULL);

memset(&act, 0, sizeof(act));
sigfillset(&act.sa_mask);

act.sa_handler = SIG_DFL;

sigemptyset(&set);
sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &set, NULL);

execve(...);
```

But child process ignores signals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sigaction()` doesn't store the sigaction object by reference.
After you change `act.sa_handler` to `act.sa_handler = SIG_DFL`, you need to repeat to those `sigaction()` calls.

```
sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL);
sigaction(SIGQUIT, &act, NULL);
sigaction(SIGTSTP, &act, NULL);
sigaction(SIGTERM, &act, NULL);
sigaction(SIGTTIN, &act, NULL);
sigaction(SIGTTOU, &act, NULL);
```

Comment: Yes, this is it! Thank you very much!